# How to make pretty ASP.Net forms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rad

Is there a RAD-way to create nice looking forms with ASP.Net webforms? I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010. Thanks!

Is there someway of having something like the DataGrid autoformat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha's Ext JS (http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) is an excellent framework on the client side for rich forms (and other UI elements)

If you want WYSIWYG visual design inside of VS2010, you'll need a third-party tool like Coolite (http://www.coolite.com/).

But if you can deal with a bit more abstraction and don't need *everything* designed literally in your IDE, I would recommend Sencha's Designer app (http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/), which is web-based. Or, hand-code the JavaScript, Sencha's syntax is well-documented.